# Python 3.x builtin functions now returning types

Tags: python, python-3.x, return-type, built-in

While I was away, something strange happened to Python (3.4) builtin functions. Functions like `map` and `zip` now return objects (not lists or tuples).

```
In [34]: map(lambda x:1, [1,2,3])
Out[34]: <map at 0x7fe27a15dac8>
```

1. When were these added to Python?
2. Why were they added?
3. And, most importantly, will this break any code of mine?

Comment: This has been the case since the 3.x line started, back in 2008. You must have been gone for a while.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147757/iterators-in-python-3

Comment: It is mainly an issue for interactive use. The majority of 2.x code works seamlessly and you only notice in the interactive interpreter.

Comment: @dawg: Not entirely. Say you `map` a list, then modify that list and convert the mapping to a list. Since the `map` is executed after the modification of the list, the conversion is taken into account where this was not done in Python 2.x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**: These are iterables, used to prevent allocating an entire list if only a limited number of elements are required. Since 3.0

I guess these are lazy function calls (or coroutines).

A lazy function call returns an object that will calculate objects only if needed.

For instance say you have a list of `1M` items, but you only need the first `3` of the map. Then the iterator, will only compute the first three.

This can also be used to perform operations on infinite lists. Say you have a list of all prime numbers. This is an iterator. Of course you can never store **all** prime numbers. You only compute the next one, if that's really necessary.

Based on the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), I would say at 3.0?

In order to *emit* all items in your iterator and convert them to a list, you can use the `list` function:

```
>>> list(map(lambda x:1, [1,2,3]))
[1, 1, 1]
```

**Example** Infinite list.

Say you use the old list `[1,2,3]` but now you want a list that repeats the given list such that the total length is `k` instead of doing all the calculus yourself (for instance determining what the last element will be, you can perform):

```
>>> from itertools import *
>>> list(islice(cycle([1,2,3]),20))
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
```

In other words, you can perform operations over the infinite iterator [1,2,3,1,2,3,...]. **Don't perform `list` on such iterators, they will cause an out of memory exception.**

As shown in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html), you can also take the `n`th element:

```
def nth(iterable, n, default=None):
    "Returns the nth item or a default value"
    return next(islice(iterable, n, None), default)
```

And thus for instance determine whether element `1337` of the infinite Fibonacci sequence is even:

```
def fibbonacci():
    i = 0
    j = 1
    while True :
        yield j
        k = j
        j = i+j
        i = k

nth(fibbonacci(),1337)
1887894200332450578485872635131438888682034332759626203734370221207918536632734791920258721345445695603925109666619483005485820744328669636758022665585261815175601673908370933079008727762461226800205778071936133115682958306317629552911384353679816770236462076654822205794785629944
```

You can define in other words a sequence that is able to calculate each element, and still perform arithmetic on the first `n`, the `k`-th,... without having to store all these values explicitly in a list per se.

Comment: `map` is not a function. In fact, `type(map) == map` not `builtin_function_or_method`.

Comment: @PythonNut: Then why is it listed at the Python builtin functions? https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html#map

Comment: Because that's the docs for Python 3.2? I don't know; it's listed as a function in the [3.4 docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#map). But it's clearly not a function... unless I'm being dumb and types are functions now.

Comment: @PythonNut: No, you can select any Python version you want (at the top of the page). And they all have a builtin `map`. I think the term is ambiguous because there is a `Type` called `map` (the iterator type) and the function `map`. They both exist, and Python chooses the right interpretation based on syntactical usage.

Comment: I see... so I suppose my question is about the `Type` map, not the function. But something like `map(lambda x: x**2, itertools.count())[:2]` doesn't seem to be useful because `map is not subscriptable`.

Comment: @PythonNut: See updated answer, you can convert your iterator to a list. And [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) enable you to return the `ith` item.

Comment: But doesn't converting the new `map` object back to a list defeat the purpose of laziness? It was a list to begin with.

Comment: @PythonNut: Python documents many types as functions if they're primarily used as callables, since "callable" is slightly more awkward a term than "function". For example, `int`, `set`, and just about everything in `itertools`. Also, `type(map) != map`; `type(map) is type`. As for converting the map instance into a list, yes, that defeats the point of laziness, so we generally don't do it. If you want a list, a list comprehension would be the usual way to go.

Comment: @user2357112 Thank you. That clears several things up. And the `type(map) == map` was apparently a clipboard fail. Anyway, this still doesn't answer (2).

Comment: @PythonNut: Well as explained before. You don't always perform a `list`. For instance `tee` enables one to pick the first `n` items and convert them to a list.

Comment: @PythonNut: Updated with an example to demonstrate the power of such iterators.